# How to build nested query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-performance

Hi below is the query to get count of different data from different tables.

```
select(
        select count(*)
        from teachers
        where teacher_status = 1
  )as teacher_count,
  (
        select count(*)
        from students
        where student_status = 1
  )as students_count,
  (
        select count(*)
        from housekeepers
        where housekeeper_status = 1
  )as housekeeping_count,
  ( 
        select count(*)
        from students
        where student_status = 1 and
              gender = "Male"
  ) as total_male_student_count,
  ( 
        select count(*)
        from students
        where student_status = 1 and
              gender = "Female"
  ) as total_female_student_count
```

Now i want to build this single query in codeigniter with the help of codeigniter builder class, so can someone guide me please..

Purpose of running single query is to minimize the database hit.

Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use: `get_compiled_select` 
like this

```
$this->db->select('count(*) as count');
$this->db->from('teacher_status');
$teacher_status = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select("select($teacher_status)as teacher_count, ... ");
this->db ...
```

And use for others.

Comment: the second select should be in a double quote not single quote.